# How to parse request body into JSON using Express

Tags: javascript, express

I have the following setup in my express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

// Automatically parse request bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.post('/', (request, response) => {
    // var message = request.body.message;
    // message.sent_by_admin = true;
    // The above two lines create an error.
    console.log(request.body);
}
```

The error I get from the two commented out lines is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'sent_by_admin' of undefined
```

When I am printing the `request.body`, I get the following in my console:

```
{ '{\n    "message": {\n        "text": "hello"\n    },\n    "recipient": {\n        "id": "123"\n    },\n    "sender": {\n        "id": "456"\n    },\n    "timestamp": 1557949612342\n}': '' }
```

The JSON I sent is this:

```
{
    "message": {
        "text": "hello"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "123"
    },
    "sender": {
        "id": "456"
    },
    "timestamp": 1557949612342
}
```

How do I convert my `request.body` into proper JSON so that I can add/remove attributes to the data and save it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you sending the json? Are you using Content-Type application/json?

Comment: @poxopox Yes, definitely.

Comment: Use the `bodyparser.urlencoded()` middleware too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013560/json-parse-nested-json-string-property-parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the client, which was sending mangled JSON data that my server could not parse. Once I tried [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), the problem simply went away.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're `POST`-ing a body which has newlines in it. Try `POST`-ing a more compressed version.

```
{"message":{"text":"hello"},"recipient":{"id":"123"},"sender":{"id":"456"},"timestamp":1557949612342}
```

Comment: The new lines shouldn't be a problem. They are just whitespace. The more troublesome part is the quotes.